# Differentiation Rules - Covariant looking Formalism of Euler-Lagrange Equation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm having a problem with the rules of differentiation in the covariant formalism of Euler-Lagrange equation. This is an example:

Let the $\mathcal{L}$ be the lagrangian of the graviton defined heuristically as:
$$\mathcal{L}=-\frac12 h \Box h +\frac13\lambda h^3+Jh$$
or
$$\mathcal{L}=-\frac12h\partial_\nu\partial^\nu h+\frac13\lambda h^3+Jh$$
We are ignoring of course spin and we are treating gravity as a simple scalar field theory. The equations of motion then are derived from the Euler-Lagrange equation:
$$\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial h}-\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu h)}=0$$
Now,
$$\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial h}=-\frac12\partial_\nu\partial^\nu h+\lambda h^2 +J$$
because $\partial (\partial_\nu h)/\partial h=0$ right?
Also,
$$\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu h)}=0$$
since
$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial(\partial_\mu h)}=0 \qquad and \qquad \frac{\partial(\partial_\nu\partial^\nu h)}{\partial(\partial_\mu h)}=0$$

But the correct equation of motion is
$$\Box h-\lambda h^2-J=0$$
So, my calculations are definitely wrong. Therefore, I would like someone to correct me and also, provide me with some online resources, or book, or list of rules about differentiation in the covariant-looking formalism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Euler-Lagrange equations for Lagrangian densities up to second order in space-time derivative are:

$$\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial h} -\partial_{\mu} \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial \left(\partial_{\mu} h\right)} + \partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu} \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial\left(\partial_\mu \partial_\nu h\right)} = 0$$

Now you have an extra term to compute.